# Can I put two graphics cards on this motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8Z68V_LX/#specifications

ASUS P8Z68-V LX

- Can I put two graphics cards with 1GB each on this motherboard?
- I am also not sure if this motherboard supports single graphics card with more than 2GB. Does it?

Comment: It only has 1 x16 PCIe slot. Probably wouldn't be a good idea. I also assume that by GPU you mean Graphics Card? The GPU is technically just the "chip" component.

Comment: @vcsjones: I count 2.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams One of them is in x4 mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - Can I put two graphics cards with 1GB each on this motherboard?

Yes.

> - I am also not sure if this motherboard supports single graphics card with more than 2GB. Does it?

The GART may not be able to map all the memory if you're running a 32-bit OS, but I can't see why not.